# Upload images with tinyMce

Tags: tinymce

I have this plugin advImage which I use in tinyMce. I want the user to be able to upload images from his own computer. However, the plugin only allows images which are on the server to be uploaded. How can I change this? If I choose an image from my desktop for uploading, the path is Content/documents/editorImages/myImage.jpg. How to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://justboil.me/) might be what you are looking for. Give it a try.

There exists [a plugin named MCImageManager](http://www.tinymce.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php) from the developers of tinymce, but this is not free.

Comment: Tnx, but I'm looking for one without php.